# Is there a way to replace set of words with different set in R?

Tags: r, regex, string, text-mining

I am trying to replace some words in a text with new words. Everything looks fine and smooth. However, some words just won't change. I looked up this problem but I did not see something similar before. Here is my data

```
data <- structure(list(Event.Id = c(267583L, 314841L, 237431L, 282255L
), Comments = c("6 mile back up. 16 minute queue. // jim connell notified", 
"backed up past spirit of stl 5.5 miles // backed up to the boone bridge 6 miles // 20-30 min delay", 
"no que", "q: 2 miles")), row.names = c(27L, 44L, 77L, 82L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried the following code:

```
 a<- c("^q$", "^que$", "^q:$", "^veh$",  "^mi$", "^backup$","^back up$","^backed up$","^w/$","^rte$")
b<- c(" queue ", " queue ", " queue ", " vehicle ", " mile ", " queue "," queue "," queue ", " with ", " route ")
names(b)<- a
data$Comments1<-str_replace_all(data$Comments,b)
```

Comment: Which words aren't being replaced? I imagine that `back up.` is not being replaced with `queue`, because of the trailing full stop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace words/phrases within longer strings if they are found in lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60822168/replace-words-phrases-within-longer-strings-if-they-are-found-in-lookup-table)

Comment: @StewartMacdonald, it is actually very weird. The same word might be replaced in one comment and not replaced in another comment! I am having a particular problem with "q:".

Comment: @jared_mamrot Thanks for the suggestion. I am working on it.

Comment: @jared_mamrot. I just tried all the solution given in your reference and they did not work. You can see them on my example data. It seems that there is a problem with spacing may be. I am not quiet sure but this might be the main problem I am having here. However, I could not solve it.

Comment: The spacing is causing issues, e.g. " q: " isn't being replaced because it doesn't exist in your text; you have "q: " (no space in front). If you fix the spacing, do you still have a problem?

Comment: @jared_mamrot The problem is, these texts are messy and there are a lot of them, I cannot go over them all. I tried this code(please see the update). I believe this is what I need, anchors at the start and end of each word.

Answer (score 0):

It is very tricky how statements can be. I have a very big data and it is almost impossible to go over each text to see how it looks like. Therefore, I assumed all the scenarios and I wrote the following code to pick any match.

```
a<- c("^q$", "^que$", "^q:$", "^veh$",  "^mi$", "^backup$","^back up$","^backed up$","^w/$","^rte$",
      " q ", " que ", " q: ", " veh ",  " mi ", " backup "," back up "," backed up "," w/ "," rte ",
      " q$", " que$", " q:$", " veh$",  " mi$", " backup$"," back up$"," backed up$"," w/$"," rte$",
      "^q ", "^que ", "^q: ", "^veh ",  "^mi ", "^backup ","^back up ","^backed up ","^w/ ","^rte ")
b<- c(" queue ", " queue ", " queue ", " vehicle ", " mile ", " queue "," queue "," queue ", " with ", " route ",
      " queue ", " queue ", " queue ", " vehicle ", " mile ", " queue "," queue "," queue ", " with ", " route ",
      " queue ", " queue ", " queue ", " vehicle ", " mile ", " queue "," queue "," queue ", " with ", " route ",
      " queue ", " queue ", " queue ", " vehicle ", " mile ", " queue "," queue "," queue ", " with ", " route ")
names(b)<- a
data$Comments1<-str_replace_all(data$Comments,b)
```

Comment: This is a complex way to go about it. You have written multiple matches where the only difference are the start/end of string characters (and these won't match at all). For example you can replace the various iterations of "queue" with something like "[q]{1}[ue:]+" as this will match all of your examples.

Also should be replacing with the exact word, such as "queue" without spaces rather than having leading + trailing spaces included.